# Word Document properties

Tags: properties, word

We are using Sharepoint WSS 3.0 and MS Office 2007.  When ever we create or update a document's 'effective date' in the document's properties (under Prepare--> properties) and save to the server, it adds an extra day to the 'effective date' when shown in the document library.

Example: 
Document properties: Effective date- 6/3/11
Sharepoint document library column: Effective Date- 6/4/11

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

First thought is to check the time/date and time zone on the servers in your SharePoint farm, then check the time zones for the web applications, then check the time zones on the client machine. Sounds like there is something that is not coordinated in those locations.

Comment: It isn't pulling a date off of anything on the server or machine.  It should just be pulling the date field from the document, which can have a completely different date than the 'today' date.

Comment: Yes, but my thought is that the properties of that date include the timezone where the date was set, and would adjust it to match what the date would be on the servers.